# How to Download Blender Pose Library ? As well as like in Maya Studio Library (Facial Expression)

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on

Just learning about posing characters and found I have a library (vers. 2.79) but see that it is empty. Is there a repository out there somewhere of free poses I can install in my Blender library?

Answer (score 2):

Stored poses have to correspond to the armature that you are using - so any library of poses that could be applied woudl have to be rig specific. If you are using the existing empty pose library with your rig, you can pose the rig and then add the current pose to the library, and name each pose as you go. Then you can call up those poses when working in the dopesheet to set your main pose to pose action.